# Extracting text from output

Tags: powershell

I am creating my first application with VS and PowerShell and need to get the name of a service from my listview.  The output of the selection looks like this:

```
ComputerName  Status Name    DisplayName            
------------  ------ ----    -----------            
PC           Running Appinfo Application Information
```

What I want to do is get the value `Appinfo` from the `Name` column and assign it to a variable. I've had no luck with regex, but then again I am a beginner so I could be doing something wrong.  Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: That output most likely means it's an object. Did you try `$x.Name`?

Comment: Second what @jpmc26 is asking. Where does this data come from?

Comment: Also... A you doing graphical in PowerShell? (I base this on the fact that `ListView` appears to be Windows Forms of WPF class.) That would inspire a gigantic, "WAT!" from me.

Comment: You don't need to parse text. The output is an object. As jpmc26 said, just request the `Name` property of the object.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, yes it is a WPF form.  Looks like the .name worked for the value.  Is there a recommended method for doing a graphical interface for powershell?  I just saw a blog post on WPF and started following the steps and adding my code, but if there is an easier way I'm all ears.  Thanks again!

Comment: I would generally expect that you would just write C# code for a GUI. PowerShell is generally designed for automated scripting or command line usage. It would be like trying to write a GUI in Bash... Wrong tool for the job. What do you need to do with your GUI?

Comment: I really don't have any requirements for the tool; just making it for my own personal use and to practice.  For the GUI I'm using XAML and Visual Studio...stumbled across this blog and wanted to give it a shot: http://foxdeploy.com/2015/04/10/part-i-creating-powershell-guis-in-minutes-using-visual-studio-a-new-hope/

Comment: @jpmc26 There's a bunch of system-related tasks that can be done in a way more concise and readable fashion in PowerShell than if you were to implement them in C# on your own. Building GUI's on top of scripts was a core part of the original "vision" for PowerShell (see the Monad Manifesto by Jeffrey Snover for reference)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I guess that was part of the intention... but personally, I'd still opt for (at minimum), writing a tool in C# that outputs what I need to stdout and then piping it somewhere in PowerShell. Ideally, I wouldn't be using a GUI for system tasks like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output you're currently getting is a formatted (tabular) view on selected properties of an object (namely the properties `ComputerName`, `Status`, `Name`, and `DisplayName`). You can get the value of a particular property by expanding it via the `Select-Object` cmdlet:

```
$name = ... | Select-Object -Expand Name
```

You could also store the object in a variable and access the property via dot-notation:

```
$obj  = ...
$name = $obj.Name
```

Beware that if a cmdlet outputs multiple objects the variable will contain an array:

```
PS C:\> $services = Get-Service
PS C:\> $services.GetType().FullName
System.Object[]
PS C:\> $services.Count
136
```

You can access properties of a member object by index:

```
$services[42].Name
```

or by selecting a specific object via its properties:

```
$services | Where-Object { $_.DisplayName -eq 'Application Information' } |
  Select-Object -Expand Name
```

Since PowerShell v3 you can also use the dot-property notation to get the value of a particular property of all array members:

```
$services.Name
```

Prior to PowerShell v3 this would have thrown an error, because the array object doesn't have a property `Name`.